# How to convert a Ruby Hash to YAML and keeping comments?

Tags: ruby, yaml, comments

How to convert a Ruby Hash to YAML **and keeping comments**?

For the following ruby example

```rb
require 'yaml'

h = {
  # The garage in Miami
  'garage_A' => {
    'car_x' => {
      # Bought in Gotham
      'name' => 'Batmobile',
      'color' => 'black'
    }
  },
  'garage_B' => {
    # Mike's bike
    'bike_m' => {
      # Cherry red
      'color' => 'red',
      'wheels' => 2
    }
  }
}

puts YAML.dump(h)
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```yaml
---
# The garage in Miami
garage_A:
  car_x:
    # Bought in Gotham
    name: Batmobile
    color: black
garage_B:
  # Mike's bike
  bike_m:
    # Cherry red
    color: red
    wheels: 2
```

Here is what I'm getting currently:

```yaml
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
garage_A:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  car_x:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    name: Batmobile                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    color: black                                                                                                                                                                                                     
garage_B:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  bike_m:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    color: red                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    wheels: 2
```

I could also be interested in the reverse operation.

Use case: A Ruby hash with teh default configuration for a tool. When the configuration file does not exist, it dumps the hash to YAML and write the configuration file. For user-friendlyness it would be better to have the comments in the configuration file rather than to have to refer to the documentation.

Comment: You cannot access comments from within your code, they get discarded during parsing.

Comment: 1. It should at least be possible for YAML -> Ruby Hash. 2. If what you say is true, how is Yard accessing comments to generate documentation?

Comment: Regarding 1) you just need a comment-aware YAML parser. 2) Yard parses the Ruby code itself. So unlike your example, it doesn't run from within the code it's trying to parsing.

Comment: You can observe that the comments are lost at parse time by replacing `puts YAML.dump(h)` with just `puts h`. To retain the comments, you'd need to actually store them as real data somewhere (only then, once they are accessible, will you be able to convert them into YAML comments)

Comment: You could of course parse the Ruby file yourself, e.g. via [`Ripper`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Ripper.html). But that is a very different approach. (see Yard's docs on [Nodes and the AST](https://yardoc.org/guides/extending-yard/writing-handlers.html#Nodes_and_the_AST))

Comment: If your intent is to write YAML, why not just start there? Why does the data need to be expressed in terms of Ruby code?

Comment: @tadman exactly. If you want to dynamically create YAML with comments then create a template in IRB. Rails does this with the `config/database.yml` file for example.

Comment: Have you looked at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403832/ruby-appending-comment-block-to-yaml-file)

Answer (score 1):

### Add Comment Keys to Each Hash

You should really template your YAML files as [here-documents](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Document+Literals), or use a templating language like [erb](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/ERB.html). If possible, you should also use more intention-revealing names for your Hash elements so that the comments are unnecessary.

Should you find you still genuinely *need* the comments, remember that neither [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/exts/json/JSON.html) nor Ruby [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html) objects natively support comments as part of their syntax. As a result, you'll need to create a "comment" key/value pair for each nested object in your Ruby Hash in order to display it within the JSON or [YAML](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/yaml/YAML.html) you generate from the Hash object. For example:

```rb
require "yaml"

# Assign a comment key to each nested element.
hash_with_comments = {
  "comment"  => "nested hashes contain 'comment' keys",
  "garage_a" => {
    "comment" => "The garage in Miami",
    "car_x"   => {
      "comment" => "Bought in Gotham",
      "name"    => "Batmobile",
      "color"   => "black",
    }
  }
}
```

Now `hash_with_comments.to_yaml` will yield the following YAML:

```yaml
---
comment: nested hashes contain 'comment' keys
garage_a:
  comment: The garage in Miami
  car_x:
    comment: Bought in Gotham
    name: Batmobile
    color: black
```

Depending on your use case, you could stop there and just ignore comment keys in whatever code parses the YAML. Otherwise, you can use the [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) block syntax (you must use a block to avoid polluting `$1` for non-matching lines) to convert the comment elements into actual comments. For example, calling:

```rb
hash_with_comments.to_yaml.gsub(/^(\s*)comment:/) { "#{$1}#" }
```

will yield the following YAML after converting the comment keys to actual comments:

```yaml
---
# each Hash contains a 'comment' key
garage_a:
  # The garage in Miami
  car_x:
    # Bought in Gotham
    name: Batmobile
    color: black
```